# Accidentally deleted 50-synaptics.conf

Tags: drivers

I have deleted 50-synaptics.conf from my Samsung ARM Chromebook --- I would love to be able to use the trackpad again. I am completely new to Ubuntu and the entire experience, so a simple, straight forward answer would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Lukasz

Answer (score 2):

That file belongs to the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package. Simply reinstalling will put it back in place:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

alternative:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```